# How to get id of parent before save in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

i have 3 models.

- Products
- Events
- Transactions

So `Products` have a relationship of One2Many with `Events` and `Events` have a relationship of One2Many with `Transactions`.

I need to store `product_id` in `Transactions` to be able to create a filter, but i can't make it if i dont previously save the parent `product`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  say that `Transactions` has many2one `event_id` and `Events` have many2one `product_id`.

you can create a many2one `product_id` in `Transactions` using related field with `store=True` to able to performe search or includ it in domains.

in you `Transactions` Model:

```py
product_id = fields.Many2one(related='event_id.product_id', store=True, readonly=True)
```

you can even create a one2many field from product to `transactions` using `iverse_name = 'product_id'`

Comment: That do not work, as i say i have one2many relationship in this form:

products > events > transactions 

and transaction have to store the parent product_id.

Comment: if you have one2many from eventes to transaction that's mean that you m2o from transaction to events

Comment: ohhhh sorry my mistake you should use related='event_id.product_id'

Comment: i edited my answer. make sure to put readonly to prevent user from editing the product_id on transactions

Comment: what you need is to store the product_id in the transactions of it's events?

Comment: product_id in transactions. I tried the method you describe but that doesnt work.

Comment: can you post your code because it should work because i used it many time. just put the m2o field and the o2m fields

Comment: You have to consider that i create a new product, then i have a treeview in form for events and i click "add new item" a this popup the form of events and this have a treeview of transactions and if i click add new item this popup the transactions form. If i save transactions, then events and then products, transactions do not have the product_id. Only if i save the product before create all the events and transactions it work like a charm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143124/discussion-between-cherif-odoo-and-mijailr).

Comment: the value of product_id is saved when you save the product information because it's related field. related field is like a compute field or proxy that get the value from the parent